# Qual a real necessidade do método "initialize" no Ruby?

Tags: ruby, construtor

```
def initialize(nome = "Anônimo", salario = 0.0)
  @nome = nome
  @salario = salario
end
```

Pra deixar mais claro, o que não consigo entender é a diferença entre usar ou não esse método numa classe e pra que propósito ele eventualmente é usado.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Para que serve um construtor?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/73530/para-que-serve-um-construtor)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se deseja a funcionalidade dele apenas ele age como um construtor e isto pode ser visto em [Para que serve um construtor?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101). Mas conceitualmente ele não é exatamente um construtor, na prática acaba sendo, salvo alguma ignorância minha em relação ao Ruby.

Na verdade, como o nome já diz, ele é um inicializador, portanto é nele que você fará tudo o que precisa para iniciar um objeto novo criado a partir desta classe. nele você pode inicializar as variáveis da classe e executar alguns algoritmos (menos comum), por exemplo abrir um arquivo, chamar algo externo, etc.

Como dito na resposta *linkada* acima a construção é um misto de alocação e inicialização. Em tese a alocação é feita em um método chamado `new`, porém ele não pode ser redefinido pelo programador, o que ele faz é padrão sempre. Sempre que ele é chamado também chama o `initialize()` que fará a parte de inicialização.

Se não usá-lo, de que forma irá inicializar as variáveis da classe? É possível fazer no `new`, mas não é considerado apropriado. Se nada for personalizado no `new` da sua classe o padrão é este método ser assim:

```
class Foo
    def self.new(*args, &blk)
        obj = allocate
        obj.initialize(*args, &blk)
        obj
    end
end
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Ruby/Initialize.rb).

Comment: A grande diferença entre o `self.new` e o `initialize` é que um está no escopo de classe e o outro de instância, respectivamente

Comment: @vnbrs boa observação. Obviamente não pode chamar o `initialize()` sem que o objeto já exista.